# How do I post multiple objects to an array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman, schema

I can't seem to get my model and routers configured right to post multiple objects to an array via mongoose. Here's my set up:

```
//Schema
const PickSchema = new Schema({
    pick: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    team: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    player: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
})

const DraftSchema = new Schema({
    draftboard: [ PickSchema ]
})

module.exports = DraftBoard = mongoose.model('user_draftboard', DraftSchema);


//Router
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const newDraft = new DraftBoard({
        draftboard: [{
            pick: req.body.pick,
            team: req.body.team,
            player: req.body.player
        }]      
    });
    newDraft.save().then(newdraftboard => res.json(newdraftboard))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ msg: 'internal error'})
)});
```

Using postman I can post one object to the array, but my payload will likely be an array of objects so I need to post multiple objects, and when I test it out in postman i get an error:

POSTMAN body that works:

```
{
   "pick": "2",
   "team": "Washington Redskins",
   "player": "Chase Young"
}
```

JSON response in POSTMAN

```
{
    "_id": "5e960a06ff3a7b3c88e680fd",
    "draftboard": [
        {
            "_id": "5e960a06ff3a7b3c88e680fe",
            "pick": "2",
            "team": "Washington Redskins",
            "player": "Chase Young"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

But multiple objects do not work:

```
{
    "pick": "2",
    "team": "Washington Redskins",
    "player": "Chase Young"
},
{
    "pick": "3",
    "team": "Detroit Lions",
    "player": "Jeff Odukah"
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 83
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put your **POST request data** into an array. Something like:

```
[{
    "pick": "2",
    "team": "Washington Redskins",
    "player": "Chase Young"
},
{
    "pick": "3",
    "team": "Detroit Lions",
    "player": "Jeff Odukah"
}]
```

> Remember, you can change multiple objects, they just have to be in an array. Or you can just make two different POST requests, which I find much better and more simple. You do not have to go crazy on your own!

I hope that helps, and solves your issue. Comment if you need any more help or assistance!

Comment: When I do that, my catch error gets thrown `msg: 'internal error'`

Comment: Well, then it just means that you have not set properly you schema to accept multiple objects at once. Again, I highly recommend you send two different requests. It is far simpler, do not try to be everything perfect, as I did for a lot of time. It just wasted my time trying to exploring new things and delayed me from my whole project.